# Pulsating opacity effect with JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a kind of simple request to my application, but I am not sure which is the best solution for that.

Lets say I have 10 buttons and I want only one button with the opacity of 1.0. The buttons next to them should have 0.6 and the next ones 0.4. All other have 0.2.

Now I want a timeline which make a pulsating animation. The button which has the opacity of 1.0 should go to 0.2 until the previous button start raising the opacity and reached the value of 0.4.

I can't describe it better right now, but I think most people know the effect.

**First attempt**

Creating 10 timelines and start each timeline when finishing another - but I hope there is a solution with just one timeline

**Second attempt**

One timeline where each KeyFrame has a delay before starting - but I found just a delay for the whole animation.

Here's a minimal example, but I don't think that really helps because that's just the base.

```
  package com.example.demo;

  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  public class HelloApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    List<Button> allButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    VBox vBox = new VBox(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Button button = new Button("Test");
        button.setOpacity(0.2);
        allButtons.add(button);
        vBox.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    allButtons.get(1).setOpacity(0.4);
    allButtons.get(2).setOpacity(0.6);
    allButtons.get(3).setOpacity(1.0);
    allButtons.get(4).setOpacity(0.6);
    allButtons.get(5).setOpacity(0.4);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 1200, 800);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


  }
```

**Exmple opacity values during the iterations**

| Iteration | Button A | Button B | Button C | Button D | Button E | Button F | Button G | Button H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 1.0 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 1.0 | 0.6 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 1.0 | 0.6 |
| 4 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 1.0 |
| 5 | 1.0 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| 6 | 0.6 | 1.0 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 |
| 7 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 1.0 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 8 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 1.0 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 |

And then start again from iteration 1. Also a transition between those opacity values should be used so that it is a smooth transition between thos opacity values.

Many greetings,
Hauke

Comment: This needs more clarity. Also, I do not see your `Timeline` attempt. My guess is a `Timeline` with an `else-if` statement. Kinda like if a seconds hand on a clock reaches 60 seconds increment the minutes hand. That's if I am interrupting your question correctly.

Comment: Showing one of your attempts, and explaining how it doesn't work as you intend, may help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses `Timeline`, `FadeTransition`, and `ParallelTransition` to change the opacity of the buttons every second.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setSpacing(2);

        List<String> buttonTextList = new ArrayList();
        buttonTextList.add("A");
        buttonTextList.add("B");
        buttonTextList.add("C");
        buttonTextList.add("D");
        buttonTextList.add("E");
        buttonTextList.add("F");
        buttonTextList.add("G");
        buttonTextList.add("H");
                
        FadeTransition ftStepOne = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepOne.setToValue(0.2);
        FadeTransition ftStepTwo = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepTwo.setToValue(0.2);
        FadeTransition ftStepThree = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepThree.setToValue(0.4);
        FadeTransition ftStepFour = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepFour.setToValue(0.6);
        FadeTransition ftStepFive = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepFive.setToValue(1.0);
        FadeTransition ftStepSix = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepSix.setToValue(0.6);
        FadeTransition ftStepSeven = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepSeven.setToValue(0.4);
        FadeTransition ftStepEight = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(.9));
        ftStepEight.setToValue(0.2);
        List<FadeTransition> buttonStateList = new ArrayList();
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepOne);
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepTwo);
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepThree);
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepFour);
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepFive);
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepSix);
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepSeven);
        buttonStateList.add(ftStepEight);
        
        List<Button> allButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonTextList.size(); i++) {
            Button button = new Button(buttonTextList.get(i));
            button.setPrefWidth(100);
            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
            allButtons.add(button);
            vBox.getChildren().add(button);
        }
        
        final ParallelTransition parallelTransition = new ParallelTransition (); 
        parallelTransition.getChildren().addAll(buttonStateList);
                
        final Timeline timeleine = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
                
                for(int i = 0; i < allButtons.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(allButtons.get(i).getText() + "\tFrom: " + allButtons.get(i).getOpacity() + "\tTo: " + buttonStateList.get(i).getToValue());
                    buttonStateList.get(i).setNode(allButtons.get(i));                                   
                }
                               
                parallelTransition.play();
                
                FadeTransition addFtToEnd = buttonStateList.get(0);
                buttonStateList.remove(addFtToEnd);
                buttonStateList.add(addFtToEnd);
        }));
        timeleine.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        Button startBtn = new Button("Start");
        startBtn.setOnAction(event ->{
            if(timeleine.getStatus() == Animation.Status.STOPPED || timeleine.getStatus() == Animation.Status.PAUSED)
            {
                timeleine.play();
                startBtn.setText("Stop");
                System.out.println(timeleine.getStatus());
            }
            else if(timeleine.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                timeleine.pause();
                startBtn.setText("Start");
            }
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(startBtn);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 1200, 800);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. From their on, I can adjust it accordingly. Had considered whether one could do that with a smart binding, but all that had not worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try chaining [FadeTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html)

```java
     FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), allButtons.get(3));
     ft.setFromValue(1.0);
     ft.setToValue(0.2);
     ft.play();

     ft.setOnFinished( (e)-> { /* next Fade Transition */  } );
```

Comment: Instead of using `setOnFinished` it may be cleaner to use a `SequentialTransition`.

Comment: @Slaw, good point!

Comment: I am not quite sure, maybe I inaccurated my question. I added an example table with the values. Maybe that makes it a little bit clearer.

Comment: @Hauke, sry m8, it's not a crowdprogramming site. I've listed the all required API but you need to implement the logic yourself